# Using FromSqlRaw to retrieve data from a SQL procedure using HttpPost. Cannot return a string output

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

The controller code is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OutputString>>> Getoutput(AccountByCustomer input)
{
    string StoredProc = "exec dbo.Get_ACCOUNT_Data_To_API " +
            "@CustomerNumber = '" + input.CustomerNumber + "'" + "," +
            "@RequestClass = '" + input.RequestClass + "'" + "," +
            "@EmailAddress = '" + input.EmailAddress + "'" + "," +
            "@TransactionId = '" + input.TransactionId + "'";

    return await _context.OutputString.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToListAsync(); 
}
```

This returns:

[image: Sample Output]

I am trying to return:

```
{
    "Account": [
                   {
                       "Token": "8026F271-34FB-47F9-A465-83E9B0EF99FD",
                       "CustomerNo": "...
                       (I need to keep this string short as it contains customer data...)
                       ......
                   }
               ]
}
```

I have tried may ways, convert to string, deserialize, JsonResult -- absolutely NO success.

There are many examples in Stackoverflow, but I cannot make them work.

I assume that I need to convert "outMsg" which is a list to a string.

```
var x = await _context.OutputString.FromSqlRaw(StoredProc).ToListAsync();
```

return Convert.ToString(x);

but that never worked.

```
Json.Deserialize(x)
```

or any variations of it also failed.

I also tried to pass an output parameter to the procedure.

Using .net 7.0

Comment: Have you met [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not created object mapper for your store procedure returning result.

Create relevant object mapper and convert your store procedure result ToListAsync, then you will be able to JSON serialize & deserialize your data properly over HttPost.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var blogs = _context.OutputString.FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.zzz_Get_ACCOUNT_Data_To_API_NO_PARA {user}").AsEnumerable();
```

the key was: .AsEnumerable() -- it allowed .FirstOrDefault to return the data.

```
 var myString = blogs.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

No more "\" and the data looks clean.